# Converting ‘Odd’ Date Formats in Excel

Tags: excel, date, formatting, powerquery

I have two columns of data loaded in Power Query. The first is loaded with the month initial (i.e., J, F, M, A, M, J, J, A, S, O, N, D) and second with the year (i.e., 2022).

Any tips on how I can convert these two columns of ‘odd’ date data into a single column that’s month-end for 2022? Thanks!

Comment: Do the months repeat in sequence, all 12? Otherwise how would you distinguish Jan from June

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerQuery, assuming that the rows always start with January and continue thereafter in order, and then repeat

add column ... index column

right click transform... round down

in formula bar change from similar to this

= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.Round(_, 1), Int64.Type}})

to having this ending

= Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.Mod(_, 12), Int64.Type}})

add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
= Date.EndOfMonth(#date([Year],[Index]+1,1))
```

sample full code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Rounded Off" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.Mod(_, 12), Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Rounded Off", "Custom", each Date.EndOfMonth(#date([Year],[Index]+1,1)))
in #"Added Custom"
```